# discrete math simplify

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given P and Q are statements, and
(P->Q) =(~P v Q) 
, write the following
logical expression in its simplest form. Justify each of the steps by citing the
logical rule used.
(P ->Q ) -> Q

This was the answer given:

(P -> Q ) -> Q     For solving this statement first we substitute P->Q=~P v Q (Given).
(P ->Q ) -> Q    =     (~P v Q)->Q
Again, using the given identity P->Q=~P v Q :
~(~P v Q) v Q      =  (P Λ ~Q) v Q
By using the identity : (A Λ B) v C = A v C Λ B v C
(P Λ ~Q) v Q       =  P v Q Λ ~Q v Q
As  ~Q v Q = U (universal set)
So the result        (P -> Q ) -> Q  =   P v Q

I am trying to figure it out how thy got the answer? I didn't which logic rule they used. Please advice.

Comment: (P ->Q ) -> Q = (~P v Q)->Q

Comment: Do you understand my answer below? If not, let me know which part you do not get. It should address everything in a clear manner though.

Comment: Please look at the following for typesetting guidelines while participating on MSE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will make things clearer.
\begin{align}
(P\to Q)\to Q &\Longleftrightarrow (\neg P \lor Q)\to Q\tag{equivalence}\\
              &\Longleftrightarrow \neg(\neg P\lor Q)\lor Q\tag{equivalence}\\
              &\Longleftrightarrow (P\land \neg Q)\lor Q\tag{DeMorgan}\\
              &\Longleftrightarrow (P\lor Q)\land (\neg Q\lor Q)\tag{distributivity}\\
              &\Longleftrightarrow P\lor Q\tag{$\neg Q\lor Q$ is vacuously true}
\end{align}
If you do not understand any of those steps, only *then* would I write out truth tables to convince yourself of certain propositional equivalences.

Comment: Thanks now i got a clear picture. Just a question i understand that (¬Q∨Q) also can be considered as universal set. But this question ask to use logical rule. Does universal set fall under the same rule?

Comment: Answer this: When is $\neg Q\lor Q$ ever false?

Comment: Nope it cant be false

Comment: Exactly :) Hope it is clear to you now!

Comment: yes yes thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to down-vote your question but my feeling that you have not put any effort into that homework question. The question you are asked is routine exercise in using few elementary tautologies and it looks to me that you just open solution key and copy the answer which you don't understand. Do at least the following easier exercise. Write the truth table for the original statement 
$(P\implies Q)\implies Q$ and compare it to the truth table of $P \lor Q$.

Comment: I don't think writing out the truth table is a good idea here--I am pretty certain the OP is meant to figure this out in a deductive manner instead of simply listing out truth values and comparing them.

Comment: I understand that but it looks like he just opened a solution key and doesn't understand the first thing about computing with tautologies. Such students were always pissing me off and I wanted them to do at least something.